# Now able to read data from object in angular

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am calling an API from my component.ts file using angular.
API call is successful, however I am not able to read the data from my response.

If I print from `event`, I can get the data however if I print from the this.book there is no data.

Error I am getting is  `error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.`

component.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = params.get('id'); 
      
      this.api.GetBook(this.id).then((event) => {
        this.book = event;   

        console.log(event.name)// I can get response  
        console.log(this.book.name)  //Error
      }); 

    })
```

Data in event or this.book is:

```
{__typename: 'Book', id:'1', name: "test"}
```

Comment: Can you pls give the output of `console.log(event)`

Comment: console.log(event),console.log(this.book) and console.log(event.name) works.

console.log(this.book.event), does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over `this.book` like this:

```
console.log(this.book['name'])
```

Or you have to initialize book as object type

```
public book = {}
```

Good luck

Comment: Wecome to SO! I could not understand well what you mean in your 2nd phrase: or you have to initialize; instead of OR maybe AND?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
console.log(this.book['name']);
```

Comment: You can use interpolation:

{{ book.name }}

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a type to the event parameter, which will get rid of the type error

```js
this.api.GetBook(this.id).then((event: { id: string; name: string }) => {
 ...
}
```

or a better way is to assign a return type for the GetBook method

```js
GetBook(id):Promise< { id: string; name: string }> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...});
}
```